# MySQL Query Select using sub-select takes too long

Tags: mysql, optimization, select

I noticed something strange while executing a select from 2 tables:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id_element FROM table_2 WHERE column_2=3103);
```

This query took approximatively 242 seconds.

But when I executed the subquery

```
SELECT id_element FROM table_2 WHERE column_2=3103
```

it took less than 0.002s (and resulted 2 rows).
Then, when I did

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id IN (/* prev.result */)
```

it was the same: 0.002s.

I was wondering why MySQL is doing the first query like that, taking much more time than the last 2 queries separately? Is it an optimal solution for selecting something based from the results of a sub-query?

Other details: `table_1` has approx. 9000 rows, and `table_2` has 90000 rows.

After I added an index on `column_2` from `table_2`, the first query took 0.15s.

Comment: how many results does the inside select gives ?

Comment: Could you post the result of running `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id_element FROM table_2 WHERE column_2=3103)`. This will show what query plan and indexes MySQL is using.

Comment: @Dani the post states that the inner query returns 2 rows.

Comment: Sorry, missed it. in that case, it doesn't make sense at all.
querying 9000 rows for 2 values shouldn't take 242 secs...

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id = (SELECT id_element FROM table_2 WHERE column_2 = 3103);`?

Comment: @Marius: Because "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: The EXPLAIN:
1, 'PRIMARY', 'table_1', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 8171, 'Using where'
2, 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'table_2', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 79264, 'Using where'

Comment: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY means that MySQL will run the subquery for every row, because it thinks the subquery depends on the master row

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the query analyzer evaluates the subquery for every row.

Try replacing the subquery with an INNER JOIN, and see if that improves performance:

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2
ON         t1.id = t2.id_element
           AND t2.column_2 = 3103
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in mysql prior to ver 6.

Work around I have found is:

SELECT * FROM table_1
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id_element FROM (SELECT id_element FROM table_2 WHERE column_2=3103) as q)

Comment: Can you please add a link to the bug details?

Comment: This workaround shaved some time off on my particular query (50 secs down to 10 secs, but the two separate queries still win at a combined .7sec

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I added an INDEX for the tables (guess you already have) and used the USE INDEX directive. In your case it should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 USE INDEX(id)
WHERE id IN (SELECT id_element FROM table_2 WHERE column_2=3103);
```

To me it made things better.

Comment: Isn't your `id` field autoincrement? MySQL should know to use it without specifying it.